# Do I need to regenerate the C2DM Auth Token if the account password is changed?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I know C2DM is deprecated and code should be migrated to [Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). But we have an existing application using C2DM. The application was built for a client and the client provided the original C2DM authorization token.

Recently, it appears that C2DM messaging stopped for our application. Our theory is that the client changed the password on the Google account and we now need an updated authorization token.

Is this correct? If the Google account's password changes, do you need to create a new authentication token? I can't find any document or SO post that discusses this.

Comment: I did find https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-c2dm/m20Kwuxu2sM says "it seems the password was changed on the email account linked to the c2dm. this made the token invalid.... tricky stuff."